# don't perform database query request during ajax call if request was already done and data is available

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, ajax, abort

I have a button in my view that when clicked triggers an ajax request for data on the database. Then I show the data in my page. I want to be able to hide the data if the button is clicked again and show it if it's clicked a second time and so on. I don't want to perform a new DB query everytime I click it.

so for example my request is like this:

```
$.ajax({

            url: '../route/button,
            type: 'get',
            data: {_method: 'get', _token: token},
            success: function (data) {

            // bla bla get data from DB and insert in div

       });
```

so once I clicked I have the data, then I click the button again and I want to toggle(); the div and data disappears from page but then if I click again I want to just toggle the div again and show the data that's already there without performing the DB query again.
Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to save the data from the ajax request. Then each time the button is clicked check to see if you have data saved. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7gn0gfgy/) for an example.

```
;(function() {
  var data = null,
      $output = $('#output');
  $output.hide();
  $('#button').on('click', function() {
    if (data === null) {
      // ajax request
      data = {
          foo: 'bar'
      };
      console.log('fetching data');
      // populate table with data
    }
    $output.toggle();
  });
})();
```

Comment: yes man, it works. I was setting a variable but I was making some errors. Thanks.